# How to describe computer skills in an application form? (Master's degree)

Tags: application, computer-science

In a part of the application form I was asked to describe my computer skills. How should I do this? Is mentioning them as a list (bullet points) enough, or should I be more detailed?

I'm talking about professional skills (e.g. programming languages)So should I, for example, list all the programming languages I know, or should I give detailed information (for instance, the duration I have been working with each language)?

Comment: I suggest you look into another question that has been posted on SE about how to describe programming language skills. The end result was that there is no perfect way, but the number of years you've actually worked with each language was one of the least debated ways of describing your experience IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Computer skills can be divided into several area such as Basic Skills (Windows, Office), Business skills (Mail, Internet, Communication) to more professional skills Programming, Administration, Database, Network, Consulting, but these are really big areas. There is also Academic Computer Skills where should be software regarded to academic world (Latex, Open Source....)

It is a really wide field, so maybe you should give more specific information about study programme for more information.

Comment: @Bewildered please edit your question to clarify it rather than posting important information in a comment